# matlab2tikz - problem with german letters - ä, ö, ü, \cdot and r_N

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels, axis, matlab2tikz

I'm using matlab2tikz the first time and get some problems with the first graph. I could seperate the problem. In the moment, I insert german letters like ä, ö, ü or special code like \cdot and r_N in MatLab, using matlab2tikz and compile my Latex document, I got an error.

The figure has to look like the picture attacht[image]

An image of the Error is attached:
[image]

The Latex packages I use are:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}      
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx, subfig} 
\graphicspath{{Bilder/}} 
            
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}
        
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
            
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\begin{document} 
    
\begin{figure}
\centering
\input{img/KOSTRA_S24_Z78_r_N.tikz}
\caption{Kostra 2010R Spalte 24 Zeile 78 für die Niederschlagspende}
\label{kostra_2010R}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The graph looks after compiling in Latax without the letters and special code like this:[image]

The compiled code of matlab2tikz:

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
\definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.92900,0.69400,0.12500}%
\definecolor{mycolor4}{rgb}{0.49400,0.18400,0.55600}%
\definecolor{mycolor5}{rgb}{0.46600,0.67400,0.18800}%
\definecolor{mycolor6}{rgb}{0.30100,0.74500,0.93300}%
\definecolor{mycolor7}{rgb}{0.63500,0.07800,0.18400}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=15.5in,
height=8.175in,
at={(2.6in,1.103in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=100,
xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
xlabel={Jährlichkeit [a]},
ymin=0,
ymax=1200,
ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
ylabel={$\text{Niederschlagspenden r}_\text{N}\text{  [l/(s}\cdot\text{ha)]}$},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
title style={font=\bfseries},
title={KOSTRA S24 Z78},
legend style={at={(0.139,0.692)}, anchor=south west, legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   55\\
2   73\\
3   84\\
5   97\\
10  115\\
20  133\\
30  143\\
50  157\\
100 175\\
};
\addlegendentry{5 min}

\addplot [color=mycolor2]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   87\\
2   112\\
3   126\\
5   145\\
10  170\\
20  196\\
30  210\\
50  229\\
100 254\\
};
\addlegendentry{10 min}

\addplot [color=mycolor3]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   107\\
2   138\\
3   156\\
5   178\\
10  209\\
20  240\\
30  258\\
50  280\\
100 311\\
};
\addlegendentry{15 min}

\addplot [color=mycolor4]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   121\\
2   157\\
3   177\\
5   203\\
10  239\\
20  274\\
30  295\\
50  321\\
100 356\\
};
\addlegendentry{20 min}

\addplot [color=mycolor5]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   140\\
2   183\\
3   208\\
5   240\\
10  283\\
20  326\\
30  351\\
50  383\\
100 426\\
};
\addlegendentry{30 min}

\addplot [color=mycolor6]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   156\\
2   209\\
3   239\\
5   278\\
10  330\\
20  382\\
30  413\\
50  451\\
100 504\\
};
\addlegendentry{45 min}

\addplot [color=mycolor7]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   166\\
2   226\\
3   261\\
5   305\\
10  366\\
20  426\\
30  461\\
50  505\\
100 565\\
};
\addlegendentry{60 min}

\addplot [color=mycolor1]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   182\\
2   246\\
3   283\\
5   330\\
10  394\\
20  458\\
30  495\\
50  542\\
100 606\\
};
\addlegendentry{90 min}

\addplot [color=mycolor2]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   195\\
2   261\\
3   300\\
5   349\\
10  416\\
20  482\\
30  521\\
50  570\\
100 637\\
};
\addlegendentry{2 h}

\addplot [color=mycolor3]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   214\\
2   285\\
3   326\\
5   378\\
10  449\\
20  519\\
30  561\\
50  613\\
100 684\\
};
\addlegendentry{3 h}

\addplot [color=mycolor4]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   229\\
2   302\\
3   346\\
5   400\\
10  474\\
20  547\\
30  591\\
50  645\\
100 719\\
};
\addlegendentry{4 h}

\addplot [color=mycolor5]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   251\\
2   329\\
3   375\\
5   433\\
10  511\\
20  590\\
30  635\\
50  693\\
100 771\\
};
\addlegendentry{6 h}

\addplot [color=mycolor6]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   276\\
2   359\\
3   408\\
5   469\\
10  552\\
20  635\\
30  684\\
50  745\\
100 828\\
};
\addlegendentry{9 h}

\addplot [color=mycolor7]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   295\\
2   382\\
3   432\\
5   496\\
10  583\\
20  670\\
30  721\\
50  785\\
100 871\\
};
\addlegendentry{12 h}

\addplot [color=mycolor1]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   324\\
2   416\\
3   470\\
5   538\\
10  630\\
20  722\\
30  776\\
50  844\\
100 936\\
};
\addlegendentry{18 h}

\addplot [color=mycolor2]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   346\\
2   442\\
3   498\\
5   569\\
10  666\\
20  762\\
30  818\\
50  889\\
100 985\\
};
\addlegendentry{24 h}

\addplot [color=mycolor3]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   426\\
2   524\\
3   581\\
5   653\\
10  750\\
20  848\\
30  905\\
50  977\\
100 1075\\
};
\addlegendentry{48 h}

\addplot [color=mycolor4]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   481\\
2   580\\
3   637\\
5   710\\
10  809\\
20  907\\
30  965\\
50  1037\\
100 1136\\
};
\addlegendentry{72 h}

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=20in,
height=10.031in,
at={(0in,0in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
axis line style={draw=none},
ticks=none,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

I have an Win10 system and use MikTex 2.9. Did every Update I could ....
Is it a problem to run the system with an English language? Cann't change it at the moment. A simulation is running for the next 24 hours.

I like to use vector graphics. I can use png but it looks bad.

Thanks for the help
Kopi

I did the update over the MikTeX Console. At some point the admin mode was necessary.  5 minutes ago, I did a new update .  You are rigth, the image of a compile without the problematic letters and code. If I change the \documentclass to \documentclass[tikz]{standalone} I get the full error report. This time I uncomment some of my latex document code. That's why is the error message shorter.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem. I would personaly advise you to compile your `matlab2tikz` generated pictures separately from your document, and include them afterwards with an `\includegraphics` call. Though this is my personal taste, I believe it saves a lot of compilation time for large documents.

Comment: After adding `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}`, all the packages you mention and a `\begin{document} ... \end{document}` to the `matlab2tikz` script it compiles fine. Can you post an example showing the problem ?

Comment: Regardless of some old packages, your last code compiles fine on my system (Win10 + MiKTeX) can you update your packages and see if it helps ?

Comment: I updated every thing I could find. The error is still there. It says, that the error has still something to do with \end{axis}.I try it tomorrow again.

Comment: Hi, I have a problem with german letters ä, ü, ö, the code \cdot an r_N. But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: How exactly did you update? If you're using miktex the remember to update in both miktex user mode and (if applicable) in miktex admin mode (miktex can place packages in two places which can shadow over each other).

Comment: You should probably also reduce the generated to to only something relevant that gives the error. Please only show the error from the example you give, the image of the error is clearly from a different document

Comment: I attachted the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was created by the compiling of matlab2tikz. If I delete the command \text{} in the x- ans y-label, then I donnt' get the error. Has someone an answer, why this happend? There is only one problem left. The legend.

See picture attached:

[image]

I use at the moment the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfig}
\graphicspath{{img/}}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

%Für Vektorgrafiken
\usepackage{color}
%\graphicspath{img/}
\usepackage{transparent}
%Für TikZ

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document} 

%\begin{figure}
%\centering
%\input{img/KOSTRA_S24_Z78_r_N.tikz}
%
%\caption{Kostra 2010R Spalte 24 Zeile 78 für die Niederschlagspende}
%\label{kostra_2010R}
%\end{figure}

% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
\definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.92900,0.69400,0.12500}%
\definecolor{mycolor4}{rgb}{0.49400,0.18400,0.55600}%
\definecolor{mycolor5}{rgb}{0.46600,0.67400,0.18800}%
\definecolor{mycolor6}{rgb}{0.30100,0.74500,0.93300}%
\definecolor{mycolor7}{rgb}{0.63500,0.07800,0.18400}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=3.5in,
height=3.175in,
at={(2.6in,1.103in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=100,
xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
xlabel={Jährlichkeit [a]},
ymin=0,
ymax=1200,
ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
ylabel={Niederschlagspenden $r_N$ $[l/(s\cdot ha)]$},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
title style={font=\bfseries},
title={KOSTRA S24 Z78},
legend style={at={(0.139,0.692)}, anchor=south west, legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   55\\
2   73\\
3   84\\
5   97\\
10  115\\
20  133\\
30  143\\
50  157\\
100 175\\
};
\addlegendentry{5 min}

\addplot [color=mycolor2]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   87\\
2   112\\
3   126\\
5   145\\
10  170\\
20  196\\
30  210\\
50  229\\
100 254\\
};
\addlegendentry{10 min}

\addplot [color=mycolor3]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   107\\
2   138\\
3   156\\
5   178\\
10  209\\
20  240\\
30  258\\
50  280\\
100 311\\
};
\addlegendentry{15 min}

\addplot [color=mycolor4]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   121\\
2   157\\
3   177\\
5   203\\
10  239\\
20  274\\
30  295\\
50  321\\
100 356\\
};
\addlegendentry{20 min}

\addplot [color=mycolor5]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   140\\
2   183\\
3   208\\
5   240\\
10  283\\
20  326\\
30  351\\
50  383\\
100 426\\
};
\addlegendentry{30 min}

\addplot [color=mycolor6]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   156\\
2   209\\
3   239\\
5   278\\
10  330\\
20  382\\
30  413\\
50  451\\
100 504\\
};
\addlegendentry{45 min}

\addplot [color=mycolor7]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   166\\
2   226\\
3   261\\
5   305\\
10  366\\
20  426\\
30  461\\
50  505\\
100 565\\
};
\addlegendentry{60 min}

\addplot [color=mycolor1]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   182\\
2   246\\
3   283\\
5   330\\
10  394\\
20  458\\
30  495\\
50  542\\
100 606\\
};
\addlegendentry{90 min}

\addplot [color=mycolor2]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   195\\
2   261\\
3   300\\
5   349\\
10  416\\
20  482\\
30  521\\
50  570\\
100 637\\
};
\addlegendentry{2 h}

\addplot [color=mycolor3]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   214\\
2   285\\
3   326\\
5   378\\
10  449\\
20  519\\
30  561\\
50  613\\
100 684\\
};
\addlegendentry{3 h}

\addplot [color=mycolor4]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   229\\
2   302\\
3   346\\
5   400\\
10  474\\
20  547\\
30  591\\
50  645\\
100 719\\
};
\addlegendentry{4 h}

\addplot [color=mycolor5]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   251\\
2   329\\
3   375\\
5   433\\
10  511\\
20  590\\
30  635\\
50  693\\
100 771\\
};
\addlegendentry{6 h}

\addplot [color=mycolor6]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   276\\
2   359\\
3   408\\
5   469\\
10  552\\
20  635\\
30  684\\
50  745\\
100 828\\
};
\addlegendentry{9 h}

\addplot [color=mycolor7]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   295\\
2   382\\
3   432\\
5   496\\
10  583\\
20  670\\
30  721\\
50  785\\
100 871\\
};
\addlegendentry{12 h}

\addplot [color=mycolor1]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   324\\
2   416\\
3   470\\
5   538\\
10  630\\
20  722\\
30  776\\
50  844\\
100 936\\
};
\addlegendentry{18 h}

\addplot [color=mycolor2]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   346\\
2   442\\
3   498\\
5   569\\
10  666\\
20  762\\
30  818\\
50  889\\
100 985\\
};
\addlegendentry{24 h}

\addplot [color=mycolor3]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   426\\
2   524\\
3   581\\
5   653\\
10  750\\
20  848\\
30  905\\
50  977\\
100 1075\\
};
\addlegendentry{48 h}

\addplot [color=mycolor4]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1   481\\
2   580\\
3   637\\
5   710\\
10  809\\
20  907\\
30  965\\
50  1037\\
100 1136\\
};
\addlegendentry{72 h}

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=10in,
height=1.031in,
at={(0in,0in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
axis line style={draw=none},
ticks=none,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%



\end{document}
```

After changing the matlab Code to UTF-8 and using matlab2tikz again I got this error message.
[image]

Comment: Well it is good for you that you found a workaround. However your original code compiles just fine for me. It probably means that the `\text` triggers the issue on your system, but it is unlikely to be a robust solution.

Comment: OKAY, can you compile my Latex code for my master thesis in 6 month? :)

Comment: Nope, :). If the workaround allows you to work without trouble, that is good. But if you have to correct each plot manually that will cost you time. And you may end up here again in a few weeks because the issue is not really solved, and another example may trigger it. Did you try to compile the `tikzpicture` as a standalone document ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. Didn't work. Or did you mean, I should change to the compiled code of Matlab2tikz \documentclass[tikz]{standalone} \begin{document} ... \end{document} extend. And then load it as a graphic?

Comment: I figured something else out. I loaded the compiled Matlab2tikz code with texmaker and it said that I have "ISO-8859-1" and not "UTF-8". I changed it, but the problem is still there. I follow the track.

Comment: I meant to compile the figure inside a `standalone` yes. And then include it as a graphic